# Retrieve data with web api from one localhost application to another localhost application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm working with two individual mvc application like A and B. I'm running these two application on localhost(IIS). On application A i have an api controller called student. Now i want these student data through student api and show on application B. How can i retrieve those data through this student api?
i try this ajax request from application B,

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://localhost:123/api/StudentApi',
   type: "GET",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
   },
   error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
      }
   });
```

Comment: are you getting any error.

Comment: no. there is no error but return undefined.

Comment: there are few things you can do here. 1) first, check with Postman if your API Project/Application A, is returning. we need to make sure that your API project is running fine. 2) Then, Project B, since it is javascript, see if you can run it from visual studio code or as a node project, that will make it easy to debug and isolate problems.